# several instances accesing same disk

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have an network of industrial sensors, this sensors upload csv files to an ubuntu instance in google compute engine, we recieve at least 10 files each minute, this files have between 30 - 2000 lines with several values.

I have a python script processing this files running each minute, but sometimes the script isn't able to process all the files whithin the minute, I send the info to a mysql db (I need to update a dashboard every minute) so I would like to run this script in several instances, each one processing files. (I have a mysql table where i keep control of wich file is being processed or hasn't been processed yet)

So How I could share the disk where the csv file are being stored between several instances without the need to run rsync?

Also, I don't see using google cloud storage as an option, because I'd requiere to upload the files to gcs then sync the folder in each instance using the gscloud command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

I would still advice you to use Cloud storage as intermediate and use [Object Change Notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification). GCS will then starting sending push notifications that a file arrived. If your script fails, you will get exponential backoff.

Run your python script on Appengine to handle the push notifications so you will automatically scale with the frequency of the incoming files.

Your question regarding the shared disk : you can mount a disk on 16 instances at once if all mounts are READONLY. You can only mount to 1 GCE instance when mounted READWRITE. So you will need to copy your data around, no way around it.

Comment: thank you for your input @koma , if i understood correctly your optimal solution would be:
1. rsync the incoming files from the ubuntu instance to the gs bucket
2. enable push notifications for that bucket
3. run the script in app engine and each notification handle a file?

Comment: Yes. If you are in control of the upload process, you could redirect that straight to GCS, then there is no need for intermediate instance to do the uploading to GCS.

Comment: I'm new to gs cloud, but it's possible to read a csv file as if they were local in a python script running in appengine? or do I can invoke a script running in my instance?

Comment: You can read/write using the API client : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted

Comment: Cool, thank you, The only problem is my sensors just can upload the info to fixed location using post so I'd required to rsync between the instance and the gs bucket, anyway, with your suggestion I think i can handle adding more devices to the network.

Comment: @user2987151 there's the eitquette of accepting the answer on stackoverflow if you're happy with it. thx !